# Getting Incorrect RGB Value from GOES-16 Satellite L2 Files

Tags: python

I have tried Brian Blaylock's attempt at creating a true color RGB image from GOES-16 satellite data via channels 1, 2, and 3 with enhancement.

https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/mapping_GOES16_TrueColor.html

https://github.com/blaylockbk/pyBKB_v3/blob/master/BB_GOES/GOES16_TrueColor_Cartopy.ipynb

I've tried recreating their method but my images come out very different...

```py
nc = xarray.open_dataset("OR_ABI-L2-MCMIPC-M6_G16_s20191851801261_e20191851804034_c20191851804149.nc")

red = nc.variables['CMI_C01'][:]
green = nc.variables['CMI_C03'][:]
blue = nc.variables['CMI_C02'][:]

# for imshow, r,g, and b values need to be clipped
red = np.clip(red,0,1)
green = np.clip(green,0,1)
blue = np.clip(blue,0,1)
```

Mimicking the square root function:
[image]

```py
red = np.power(red,(1/2))
green = np.power(green,(1/2))
blue = np.power(blue, (1/2))

# GOES doesn't have a true green band, so a little weighting will attempt to get a true green color from the red, blue, and near IR green (veggie)
green_true = 0.45*red + 0.1*green + 0.45*blue
green_true = np.clip(green_true,0,1)

fig, ([ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]) = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(16, 3))

ax1.imshow(red, cmap='Reds', vmax=1, vmin=0)
ax1.set_title('Red', fontweight='semibold')
ax1.axis('off')

ax2.imshow(green, cmap='Greens', vmax=1, vmin=0)
ax2.set_title('Veggie', fontweight='semibold')
ax2.axis('off')

ax3.imshow(green_true, cmap='Greens', vmax=1, vmin=0)
ax3.set_title('"True" Green', fontweight='semibold')
ax3.axis('off')

ax4.imshow(blue, cmap='Blues', vmax=1, vmin=0)
ax4.set_title('Blue', fontweight='semibold')
ax4.axis('off')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.02)
```

[image]

## Expected: [image]

```py
rgb = np.dstack([red,green_true,blue])
rgb_eh = np.dstack([red,green,blue])

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 3))

ax1.imshow(rgb)
ax1.set_title('RGB?', fontweight='semibold')
ax1.axis('off')

ax2.imshow(rgb_eh)
ax2.set_title('RGB?', fontweight='semibold')
ax2.axis('off')
```

[image]

## Expected:[image]

Is there any glaring error that I've missed?
Thanks for the help

Comment: HI - FYI this is the wrong unidata tag - this is for the unidata DB as now owned by Rocket.

Comment: I don't have an answer on the error, but I have a working .exe that inputs L1b files and creates the same true color image. Let me know if you would like it. It's in .exe format and I don't have the source code, but if you are just wanting the imagery itself, it will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was a year ago, but if it is useful for any else I leave my answer.
Your code has the bands loaded in the wrong order. The correct order would be red in chanel 2 (CMI C02) and Blue in channel 1 (CMI C01):

```
red = nc.variables['CMI_C02'][:]  # The CH2 is the 0.64 um (red)
green = nc.variables['CMI_C03'][:]
blue = nc.variables['CMI_C01'][:]  # The CH1 is the 0.47 um (blue)
```

Thanks for put the links about enhancement of the images! I was looking for this.